# TabBarController disappears when I segue back to the view from another view

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a viewController that is embedded in a nav controller. This nav controller is then embedded in a tab bar controller.

I have another viewController that is not supposed to be accessible from the tabBarController. It should only be accessible from the first viewController using a button. From the secondViewController, I made a UIBarButtonItem to move back to the original view. From the first view to the second view  and vice versa, I used a Storyboard reference to move to and from from the views.

However, when I move from the first view to the second view, the tab bar controller disappears (like it should). When I move back to the first view, the tab bar controller disappears and I cannot move between tabs anymore.

I tried including:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

on the first view and

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

on the second view

and nothing seems to work. The tab bar controller disappears every time i move from the second view to the first view.

Comment: in which method you add this `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false`?

Comment: How do you "move back to the original view"? There should be only **one** storyboard reference between the two view controllers. Since they are embedded in a navigation controller you can simply push and pop the second view controller.

Comment: Hi André, so I only need one storyboard reference then? How do I move from the second view controller to the first then?

Comment: Hi Vinu, I put it in viewDidAppear

Comment: Add `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false` this in your `ViewWillAppear()` method.

Comment: Yes, you do. In the second view controller you can simply call `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are following a wrong hierarchy. You are actually using seagues to go back and forth. This creates a new instance every time you try to come back to the first controller.

Let's make it clear:

**You need to follow the below approach:**

**1** You have two controllers A and B.

**2** Use self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear of controller A.

**3** Controller A is embedded in a navigation controller which is further embedded in a UITabBarController.

Tapping a button in controller A, you need to push to controller B. So you can use segue for this or you can do it programatically like:

```
let controllerB = B()
A.navigationController?.pushViewController(controllerB, animated: true)
```

**4** Go Back to Controller A on the tap UIBarButtonItem. So your code in the action of UIBarButtonItem should be something like:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

**Remember you should not should segue to go back to the previous controller.**

Comment: Hey, I am a bit confused. How do I get from controller B back to controller A then? If I were to use this: self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Comment: PopViewController does that for you. It is for popping back to the previous controller.

Comment: Great! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

you should use

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

in that controller where the back button is placed, I am using the exact scenario in one of the my app.